# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function. Composable function on lauchedEffect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm new to compose and i have an issue i dont know how to solve. 
Here is my issue, i'm working on a system that reads a document via an external device.
I have 2 different screen. One is the screen where the reading prosess is done(`ScanDocument`) and an other one That displays informations when the read is done(`SuccesError`).
When i get an error my app displays the `SucessError` screen and after a few second i want to go back to the `ScanDocument`, but the way i do it throws this error `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`.
How can i do what i intend to do?

here is the code of both pages:

```
@Composable
fun ScanDocument(
 messageId: Int,
 showSpinner: Boolean,
 onCancel: () -> Unit,
 inactivityTimer: IInactivityViewModel,
 animationId: Int,
) {

Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(800.dp)
        .height(1280.dp)

) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(800.dp)
            .height(136.dp)
            .padding(start = 32.dp, top = 32.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 32.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(56.dp, Alignment.Top),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(736.dp)
                .height(72.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .width(736.dp)
                    .height(72.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            ) {
                Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                EESCancelButton(
                    onClick = onCancel, modifier = Modifier
                        .width(122.dp)
                        .height(72.dp), viewModel = inactivityTimer
                )
            }
        }
    }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(2f, false)
            .width(800.dp)
            .height(800.dp)

    ) {
        Box {
            ExoplayerExample(animationId)
            if (showSpinner) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(150.dp)
                        .size(200.dp),
                    strokeWidth = 20.dp
                )
            }
        }


        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(800.dp)
                .height(150.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                    0.dp,
                    Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(800.dp)
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .weight(1f, false)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF0E3183))
                    .padding(start = 32.dp, top = 15.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 15.dp)

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = messageId),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.avenir_black)),
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(900),
                        color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    )
                )
            }
        }

    }

}}
```

ScessError

```
@Composable
 fun SuccesError(
 color: Long,
 text: Int,
 navController: NavHostController,
 passeportOrVisa:String
) {

Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(800.dp)
        .height(1280.dp)
        .background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color(color),
                    Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                )
            )
        )
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(800.dp)
            .height(136.dp)
            .padding(start = 32.dp, top = 32.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 32.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(56.dp, Alignment.Top),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(736.dp)
                .height(72.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .width(736.dp)
                    .height(72.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(2f, false)
            .width(800.dp)
            .height(800.dp)

    ) {
        Box {
            if(passeportOrVisa == "passeport"){
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.passport),
                    contentDescription = "passeport"
                )
            }else if (passeportOrVisa == "visa"){
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.visa),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 170.dp),
                    contentDescription = "passeport"
                )
            }

            when (color) {
                0xFF219653 -> {Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.valid),
                    contentDescription = "passeport",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 265.dp,top=140.dp, bottom =150.dp )
                )}
                0xFFEA0028 -> {Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.invalid),
                    contentDescription = "passeport",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 212.dp,top=140.dp, bottom =150.dp )
                )}
            }
        }


        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(800.dp)
                .height(150.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                    0.dp,
                    Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(800.dp)
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .weight(1f, false)
                    .background(color = Color(color))
                    .padding(start = 32.dp, top = 15.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 0.dp)

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = text),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.avenir_black)),
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(900),
                        color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    when (color) {
        0xFF219653 -> Settings().isPassportOk = true
        0xFFEA0028 -> Settings().isPassportOk = false
    }
    delay(3000)
    if(passeportOrVisa == "passeport"){

        if(color == 0xFF219653){
            navController.navigate(NAVIGATE_TO_IDENTITY_CARD)
        }else{
            ScanDocument(
        R.string.passport_scan_message,
        false,
        onCancel,
        viewModel.inactivityTimer,
        passportAnimationId,
    )
            )
           // navController.navigate(NAVIGATE_TO_SCAN_PASSPORT)
        }
    }
     else if(passeportOrVisa == "visa"){
        if(color == 0xFF219653){
            navController.navigate(NAVIGATE_TO_FACE_PICTURE_WARNING)
        }else{
            navController.navigate(NAVIGATE_TO_SCAN_VISA)
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Consider reading the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008743/android-jetpack-compose-understanding-composable-scopes

It goes into depth about this error and how to avoid it.